# Why do you have to put "being" here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> We think of a day as ***being*** the time from when we wake up to the time we go to sleep. Exactly when a person wakes up and goes to sleep is not important.

Shouldn't the phrase, think A as B, means A equals B? A day should be some kind of 'time', not "being the time"?

Comment: It would have been fine if you omitted _being_ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Being" has a few definitions, but it can be the present participle of the verb *to be*.

Saying "we think of the day *as being* the time from [x] to [y]" is a bit like saying "*we think it to be...*".

The reason it isn't *quite* the same as 'A equals B', as you put it, is because it is about *perception*. Your original statement is not saying that the day *is* that - but that is what people think that it is, and the phrase choice shows that.